# Garnish - Event when selecting a category

Tags: categories, garnish

I have a "Categories" field in my section. I want to perform some JavaScript actions when a category is selected.

**Is there any built-in event which will be triggered at that point?**

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this?

```
$("#fields-myCateogryField").data("elementSelect")
    .on("selectElements", function(e){console.log(e);})
    .on("removeElements", function(e){console.log(e);});
```